# Designated initialization and base classes?

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++20 (latest draft), given the following code:

```
struct B { int mb; };
struct D : B { int md; };
```

which of these six expressions are ill-formed and which are not?

```
/*1*/ D{42, 43}
/*2*/ D{{42}, 43}
/*3*/ D{42, .md = 43}
/*4*/ D{{42}, .md = 43}
/*5*/ D{.mb = 42, .md = 43}
/*6*/ D{{.mb = 42}, .md = 43}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(2) is your standard, explicit aggregate initialization. It's fine.

(1) is aggregate initialization with brace elision around the `B` subobject. This is also fine.

(3) and (4) are mixing designated initializers with non-designated initializers, which is not allowed. The grammar for [*designated-initializer-list*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:designated-initializer-list) only allows a *designated-initializer-clause*, which is a *designator* (`.` *identifier*) followed by a *brace-or-equal-nitializer*. There is no other form.

(5) and (6) are trying to designated-initialize a base class subobject, which is also not allowed. All the designators have to name direct non-static data members. [[dcl.init.aggr]/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#aggr-3.1) says:

> If the initializer list is a *designated-initializer-list*, the aggregate shall be of class type, the identifier in each designator shall name a direct non-static data member of the class, [...]

---

The [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0329r0.pdf) makes it clear that both of these are intended. It comments that:

> The base class objects will be initialized with {}. We do not have a concrete use case for somein­depth control of how to initialize the base class objects, and the proposed design is forwardcompatible, therefore we suggest to address this issue in another proposal.

and:

> Either all designators, or none.

with a future issue:

> Do we allow a designation list to appear in a list­-initializer as a suffix, e.g. `​A { 1, 2, .c= 3, .d = 4 }​` ?

Comment: Why not relax the standard and have it allow (4) above? I ran into this specifically when just trying to initialize from a `B` object that I already have: `D{{b}, .md = 43}`, or just `D{b, .md = 43}`. Both work on clang and do the expected thing. This seems simpler than the alternatives proposed in https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2287r1.html